# Generate numbers for given ranges (sql query)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a query which generate numbers between specified ranges.

I have a table

```
NUM_RANGES

ID  START_NUMBER  END_NUMBER
--  ------------  ----------
 1             1           5
 2             6          10
```

I need to get this result:

```
   ID NUMBER
   -- ------
    1      1
    1      2
    1      3
    1      4
    1      5
    2      6
    2      7
    2      8
    2      9
    2     10
```

With this query i can get correct result but only for specified id in where clause:

```
select   id, start_number + level - 1 next_tag
                        from  (select id, start_number,end_number
                        from NUM_RANGES
                        where id = 1
       ) 
        connect by level <=  end_number -  start_number + 1
```

Without "where id = 1" im getting 62 rows with duplicates where distinct helps but with bigger ranges 1 - 200 , 200- 500 it works too slow ..

Thanks for help!

Comment: How high do your end_number's need to go?

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle 12c you can use CROSS APPLY:

```
select *
from num_ranges
cross apply(
   select level - 1 + start_number as my_new_number
   from dual
   connect by level <= end_number - start_number + 1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 11.2 and earlier, you can use a hierarchical query:

```
with
     num_ranges ( id, start_number, end_number ) as (
       select 1, 1,  5 from dual union all
       select 2, 9, 12 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated input data (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins below this line.
select     id, start_number + level - 1 as nmbr
from       num_ranges
connect by level <= end_number - start_number + 1
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by   id, nmbr  --  If needed
;

        ID       NMBR
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         1          5
         2          9
         2         10
         2         11
         2         12
```

Specifically, without linking new rows to existing ones by the same `id`, you are generating an insane number of unnecessary rows. This is why you need `prior id = id`. The additional condition, `prior sys_guid() is not null`, is needed so that Oracle does not see cycles where it shouldn't see them (which are caused precisely by "`prior id = id`").

In Oracle 12.1 or higher, you can use the `lateral` clause:

```
select   n.id, l.nmbr
from     num_ranges n,
         lateral ( select start_number + level - 1 as nmbr from dual
                   connect by level <= end_number - start_number + 1 ) l
order by id, nmbr  --  If needed
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Pretty fast too.

```
with cte as (select 0 as c from dual)
, cte4 as (select c from cte union all select c from cte union all select c from cte union all select c from cte)
, cte256 as (select t0.c from cte4 t0, cte4 t1, cte4 t2, cte4 t3)
, nums as (select row_number() over(order by null) as n from cte256 t0, cte256 t1, cte256 t2)
select NR.id, nums.n as NUMBER_
from nums
join NUM_RANGES NR on nums.n between NR.START_NUMBER and NR.END_NUMBER
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
WITH recursive_query (id, nmbr, end_number ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         start_number,
         end_number
  FROM   num_ranges
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         nmbr + 1,
         end_number
  FROM   recursive_query
  WHERE  nmbr + 1 <= end_number
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id,
       nmbr
FROM   recursive_query;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE num_ranges ( id, start_number, end_number ) as
  SELECT 1, 1,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 6, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NMBR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vpLgAiUe)