# How to increase value from two columns difference in oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c

I have a table data. There has two columns, one is start number and another is end number. From these two column, how can I generate multiple row.

My data as follows

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | START_NUMBER | END_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9876 | 05584 | 05587 |
| 6789 | 3456 | 3460 |

I need to convert above data as following structure

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | START_NUMBER | END_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9876 | 05584 |  |
| 9876 | 05585 |  |
| 9876 | 05586 |  |
| 9876 | 05587 |  |
| 6789 | 3456 |  |
| 6789 | 3457 |  |
| 6789 | 3458 |  |
| 6789 | 3459 |  |
| 6789 | 3460 |  |

I have millions of data like this.

Comment: look at connect by and level to generate rows

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334977/1509264

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood the question, based on your question and comment in deleted answer. To readers who don't have enough reputation to see it, it says:

> If my data would be like as account_number (4567), start_number(234,567,456), end_number(236,568,458) in a single row, then what would be my step or query?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

ACCOUNT_NUMBER START_NUMBER    END_NUMBER
-------------- --------------- -----------
          4567 234,567,456     236,568,458
          9876 05584           05587
           777 33,65,45        ,,47
```

As you can have several values in both start and end number columns, you'll have to split each of them into rows (that's what `temp` CTE in code does), and then use one of row generator techniques to generate values between matching number values.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select
  3       account_number,
  4       regexp_substr(start_number, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, column_value, null, 1) start_number,
  5       regexp_substr(end_number  , '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, column_value, null, 1) end_number,
  6       column_value lvl
  7    from test cross join
  8      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                          connect by level <= regexp_count(start_number, ',') + 1
 10                         ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11    )
 12  select account_number,
 13    lpad(to_number(start_number) + column_value - 1, length(start_number), '0') start_number
 14  from temp cross join
 15    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 16                        connect by level <= to_number(end_number) - to_number(start_number) + 1
 17                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 18  order by account_number, lvl, column_value;
```

Result:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER START_NUMBER
-------------- ---------------
           777 33
           777 65
           777 45
           777 46
           777 47
          4567 234
          4567 235
          4567 236
          4567 567
          4567 568
          4567 456
          4567 457
          4567 458
          9876 05584
          9876 05585
          9876 05586
          9876 05587

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This question looks rather like _generate numbers and save formatting_ than _split values and generate_. I asked OP to clarify all possible inputs and matching outputs. I doubt he has comma separated values here. Even if it was the case we still don't know if he wants also comma separated output? We don't even know if account_number is unique.

Comment: @Ponder, that's how I understood the **in a single row** part of their comment.

Comment: If I were to ask such a question, I would certainly not hide the most important part at the beginning. I know how to split strings, generate rows, format values, I don't know what OP is asking. Anyway, if that's what he asked, you've got a conditional upvote :)

Comment: hahaha, @Ponder, which could easily turn into unconditional downvote :)

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks for your information. But there have some other data where for account(777)  start_number(33,65,45) and end_number(,,47) . From there I need to show data for account 777 is 33,65,45,46,47 in start number. So what would be it's process?

Comment: You'd modify regular expression a little bit. Have a look at edited code.