# ORACLE : Looking for something like generate_series

Tags: oracle

I want to create a view to somehow , show who didn't took their laptop in the last 2 weeks  ,  so we can assign them to other students. I got this table 'mouvementlaptop' which show when someone took or return their laptop (typemouvement is equals to 'entree' or 'sortie')
and the table 'etudiantLaptops' which show who Student got which Laptop (I will add something like a column that says if the student actually has the laptop or not ).
I work with oracle . If it was postgresql i could  just use Generate series to check the date, but how can i do it with oracle?
I want

1. A request to show who didn't move their laptop in the last X weeks
2. A request to show who didn't move their laptop from the date X to the date X

```sql
CREATE TABLE etudiantLaptops
(
    id varchar(100) constraint entite_etulaptop_pk primary key,
    Etudiant  VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE references ETUDIANT (ID),
    Promotion VARCHAR2(50) references promotion (id),
    reference VARCHAR2(10),
    laptops varchar2(50) references laptops(id),
    chargeur  varchar2(50) references chargeur (id),
    Remarque  VARCHAR2(200)
);

create table mouvementlaptops(
                                 id varchar(50) constraint entite_mvt_laptop_pk primary key,
                                 etudiantlaptop varchar2(50) references etudiantLaptops(id),
                                 daty date,
                                 heure varchar2(10),
                                 typemouvement varchar2(10)
);
```

I did try something like this

```sql
WITH RecursiveDates (generated_date, end_date) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2023-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT generated_date + 1, end_date
    FROM RecursiveDates
    WHERE generated_date < end_date
)
SELECT generated_date FROM RecursiveDates;
```

But I think there is an easier way to do it, but I don't know how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate numbers for given ranges (sql query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334977/generate-numbers-for-given-ranges-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you expect and why you think you need to generate a list of days.

You could just look for students when there are no entries in the movement table within the range in question using `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT Etudiant
FROM   etudiantLaptops e
WHERE  NOT EXIST(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   mouvementlaptops m
         WHERE  daty >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '7' DAY * :num_weeks
         AND    e.id = m.etudiantlaptop
       )
```

or:

```sql
SELECT Etudiant
FROM   etudiantLaptops e
WHERE  NOT EXIST(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   mouvementlaptops m
         WHERE  daty BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
         AND    e.id = m.etudiantlaptop
       )
```